# Remove None from generator output

Tags: python

How do I remove all the None values from this generator:

```
(i.get("x") for i in l)
```

I believe to can be done using assignment expressions. I tried:

```
(a:=i.get("x") for i in l if a)
```

But it returned nothing.

Comment: The `if` portion is evaluated for each `i` to decide if the current value of `i` should be used at all. `a:=i.get("x")` isn't evaluated at all *until* `if a` evaluates to true, so your current attempt is backwards. (Unless `a` already has a previously set value, the first call to `next` on your attempt should raise a `NameError`.)

Comment: That code should give you a `NameError`, unless you are not calling your generator, in which case you might as well have no code.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a version of python that supports the walrus operator (3.8+) then you can use it in your comprehension:

```py
l = [
    {"x": 1},
    {"x": 0},
    {"y": 2},
]

print([
    clean
    for i in l
    if (clean := i.get("x")) is not None
])
```

Should give you:

```
[1, 0]
```

Comment: Why use `list(...)`? Why not `[x for d in l if (x := d.get("x")) is not None]`

Comment: @Jab I wanted to highlight the generator part and I felt that using `list()` here rather than `[]` makes that more explicit. In either case, it is just so that `print()` does something meaningful. I'm happy to change it though.

Comment: I usually do `print(*(genexp))`.

Comment: That won't print it like a list literal, though.

Comment: @Chris But that's not required.

Answer (score 1):

Without the walrus operator, we can just iterate over a singleton tuple created from `i.get('x')`. This has the effect of creating a variable `x` bound to the value returned by `i.get('x')`.

```
>>> lst = [{'d': 42}, {'x': 27}]
>>> [i.get('x') for i in lst]
[None, 27]
>>> [x 
...  for i in lst
...  for x in (i.get('x'),)
...  if x is not None]
[27]
```

This does *not* account for the corner case of `'x'` being a key in one of the dictionaries with the associated value `None`.

Comment: What about `lst = [{'d': 42}, {'x': 0}]` ?

Comment: Edited to address that. Thanks!

Comment: I had to check whether that iteration is compiled away like with a singleton "list". It is.

Comment: [First optimization here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#optimizations), in case someone wonders what I mean. The announcement only shows a "list", but the linked issue also mentions tuples (and I checked with `dis`).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the walrus operator, but for a comprehension or generator the assignment has to be done in the `if` part:

```py
(a for i in l if (a:=i.get('x')) is not None)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can filter the generator result to return only the results that are not None.

```py
filter(lambda x: x is not None, (i.get("x") for i in l))
```

or

```py
(x.get("x") for x in l if x.get("x") is not None)
```

Comment: Right, but in OP's case, the test isn't whether the value yielded from the generator is None: it's whether *some function applied to that value* (in this case `.get('x')`) gives None.

Comment: There's just a step missing in the middle. E.g. `list(x for x in (i.get("x") for i in l) if x is not None)`.

Comment: It's opinion, but mixing filter/lambda with the generator expression style is ugly. Pick one and stick with it.

Answer (score -1):

You could just check if `"x"` is in the dict first:

```
l = [{'x': 1}, {'x': 0}, {'y': 2}]

result = [d["x"] for d in l if "x" in d]
```

Result:

```
[1, 0]
```

In the event you want to filter out values that are `None` as well then you could use the walrus approch:

```
result = [x for d in l if (x := d.get("x")) is not None]
```

Comment: What if `l = [{'x': None}]` ?

Comment: Depends if that is intended or not I guess but I edited